# How to stick plastic flowers to a spray-painted cigar box?

Tags: adhesives

I tried Gorilla super glue, hot glue gun, e6000, and couldnt get the plastic flowers to stick!

Comment: For those failed attempts, what part of the glue bond failed? If the separation was the result of the paint layer from the box, the paint becomes the problem, not the glue selection.

Comment: I’d try loctite ultra gel adhesive! I’ve used it for a lot of different materials and they have different kinds for specific materials too.

Comment: @L3X01D Do you know how it performs in comparison to the glues mentioned by the OP?

Comment: I’ve never used e6000 but it’s way better than either hot glue or super glue when using it on fabric and metal so I figured I’d mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The only adhesive that comes to my mind is construction silicone. A family member used clear construction silicone to glue all kinds of plastic flowers and decorative objects onto wood boards to make displays and most of the objects held so fast they had to be cut off with a knife. However, some very smooth surfaces (some plastics or varnished objects) could be peeled off easily.

If that doesn't work, consider drilling a hole through the box and the flower and fastening it with some craft wire.

Answer (score -1):

Adhering plastic flowers to a spray-painted surface can indeed be challenging due to the smooth and non-porous nature of the materials. Here are some steps and tips that might help in ensuring a better bond:

-Surface Preparation: Sanding: Begin by lightly sanding the area of the cigar box where you plan to attach the flowers. Use a fine-grit sandpaper (like 220-grit) to create a rougher surface which will help the adhesive bond better.

-Cleaning: Clean the surface thoroughly with rubbing alcohol to remove any dust, grease, or residues from the spray paint.

-Adhesive Selection: Although you've tried various adhesives, there might be others that could work better. Consider using a two-part epoxy adhesive, which is known for its strong bonding capabilities on a variety of materials.

-Application: Mix the epoxy adhesive according to the manufacturer's instructions.
Apply a thin layer of epoxy to both the cigar box and the base of the plastic flowers.

Press the flowers onto the box firmly and hold in place until the epoxy sets (usually takes a few minutes, but refer to the epoxy instructions for exact curing times).

-Clamping: If possible, use clamps to hold the flowers in place while the epoxy cures. This will ensure a strong bond.

-Curing Time: Allow the epoxy to cure completely before handling the box. Full curing time may vary, so check the manufacturer's instructions.

Additional Support: If the flowers are heavy or the bond still seems weak, consider adding additional support like a clear backing material or mounting tape.

*Professional Advice: If the issue persists, consider consulting with a local crafts store or a professional in the adhesive industry for more personalized advice.
Each adhesive behaves differently on various materials, and sometimes a bit of experimentation is needed to find the right solution.

Comment: Hi again Marsha, this post was flagged as and looks AI-generated, which would at least have to be attributed as such. While on this particular site we haven't made a policy regarding AI-generated content yet, and it's currently not banned, it is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score -4):

'E6000' is the best product ive used for glueing.
'Gorilla glues-GEL super glue' works great too[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use these products to glue plastic flowers to a cigar box, or for a similar purpose?

Comment: OP specifically says Gorilla and e6000 didn't work.